# How do I calculate the total Data values for both and display in Legend

Tags: highcharts, legend

I have created a highcharts type column for 2 series Men and Women. I want to display the total counts which is Installs and display below Legend as shown in the image.

[image: Final output image.]

How do I use the HTML with Icons with the total values.

Here is my code for the highcharts and [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/femiva/am6zjhrj/2/)

```
$(function () {
$('#stats-container').highcharts({

    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    credits: {
    enabled: false
    },
   title: null,

    xAxis: {
      categories: ['15-20', '20-25', '25-30', '30-35', '35-40', '40-45', '45-50']
    },

    yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: 90,
    pointInterval: 30,
    labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                return this.value + 'K';
      }
            },
            title: null
    },

    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' +
                this.series.name + ': ' + this.y;
        }
    },

    navigation: {
        buttonOptions: {
            enabled: false
        }
    },
            legend: {
        enabled: true,
        align: 'center',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        layout: 'horizontal'

    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Men',
        color: '#79ccde',
        data: [57.56, 82, 32, 28, 12, 13, 7],
        stack: 'male'
    }, {
        name: 'Women',
        color: '#8787f5',
        data: [33.66, 60, 35, 15, 10, 16, 9],
        stack: 'female'
    }]
});
});
```

How can I achieve the same legend with total counts and custom HTML?

Comment: The total is nowhere to be seen in your code, but `legend.labelFormatter` function is probably what you'd use to fit it in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For calculating total values of both series and displaying it in your legend you can use legend.labelFormatter:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.labelFormatter

Inside labelFormatter function you can iterate over all of your series points and add its value to sum you want to show in your label.

If you want to add image to your legend label you need to set **legend.useHTML** to **true**:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.useHTML

Then you can format your legend as HTML div. For example:

```
  labelFormatter: function() {
    var target = '<br>Target: ' + this.userOptions.target || 0,
      installs = 1,
      string, img;
    Highcharts.each(this.userOptions.data, function(p, i) {
      installs += p;
    });
    if (this.name === "Women") {
      img = '<img src = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/51/Woman_Silhouette_52.svg/2000px-Woman_Silhouette_52.svg.png" style = "width:45px"/> ';
    } else if (this.name === "Men") {
      img = '<img src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/17/Human_outline.svg" style = "width:20px"/> ';
    }
    string = '<div style = "width: 200px">' + '<div class = "leg">' + img + '</div>' + '<div class = "leg">' + this.name + target + '<br>Installs: ' + installs + '</div>' + '</div>';
    return string
  }
```

For hiding standard legend symbol you can set its width to 0:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.symbolWidth

If you want to show your tooltip the same way as you show in your image, you can use tooltip.shared property:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.shared

example:
http://jsfiddle.net/am6zjhrj/10/

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to have. I will have it implemented with the real images and update the code. Thanks @Grzegorz-Blachliński